# Maximum count of overlapping intervals in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Suppose there is a table structured as follows:

```
id    start      end
--------------------
01    00:18    00:23
02    00:22    00:31
03    00:23    00:48
04    00:23    00:39
05    00:24    00:25
06    00:24    00:31
07    00:24    00:38
08    00:25    00:37
09    00:26    00:42
10    00:31    00:34
11    00:33    00:38
```

The objective is to compute the overall maximum number of rows having been active (i.e. between `start` and `end`) at any given moment in time. This would be relatively straightforward using a procedural algorithm, but I'm not sure how to do this in SQL.

According to the above example, this maximum value would be 8 and would correspond to the 00:31 timestamp where active rows were 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 (as shown in the schema below).

[image: schema]

Obtaining the timestamp(s) and the active rows corresponding to the maximum value is not important, all is needed is the actual value itself.

Comment: If I'm following you want any row that has `0:31` in the `start` to  `end` range, correct?

Comment: hi @AdrianKlaver, sort of. I want the maximum count of overlapping intervals, nevermind the particular timestamp it happens to be.

Comment: So who/what is deciding what is active or more importantly what the value for comparison(e.g. 00:31) is? A first draft idea is `select count(*) from time_tbl where '00:31'::time between start and end`, assuming `start` and `end` are `time` fields.

Comment: Yep that's the way I was thinking of at first, using `generate_series()` to iterate every minute and get the count of active intervals for each, then take the max of this. However this can be seen as a form of Monte Carlo sampling (with one sample every minute) and I was wondering if there could exist a more quantitative manner.

Comment: Well is still not clear to me what the definition of active is? Or to put it differently what are you trying to find out?

Comment: As an example (not the actual case), you can see each row as one nurse's work shift, with the start and the end. I want to know how many nurses were working `at most` at the same time. E.g. if at any given point in history, there were at most 48 nurses working simultaneously, I want to get this value (48).

Comment: My sister, the nurse, would love to have shifts that short:) So the `BETWEEN` idea would work it just comes down to defining the interval of the points in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of at first, using generate_series() to iterate every minute and get the count of active intervals for each, then take the max of this.

You can improve your idea and iterate only "start" values from the table because one of "start" points includes in time interval with  maximum active rows.

```
select id, start,
    (select count(1) from tbl t where tbl.start between t.start and t."end")
from tbl;
```

Here results

```
id  start   count
-----------------
1   00:18:00    1
2   00:22:00    2
3   00:23:00    4
4   00:23:00    4
5   00:24:00    6
6   00:24:00    6
7   00:24:00    6
8   00:25:00    7
9   00:26:00    7
10  00:31:00    8
11  00:33:00    7
```

So, this query gives you maximum number of rows having been active

```
select
    max((select count(1) from tbl t where tbl.start between t.start and t."end"))
from tbl;
```

```
max
-----
8
```